# Kotlin with Spring DI: lateinit property has not been initialized

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I don't get Spring-based setter dependency injection in Kotlin to work as it always terminates with the error message "lateinit property api has not been initialized". I could reduce the problem to the following scenario: There is an interface

```
interface IApi {
  fun retrieveContent(): String
}
```

which is implemented by

```
class Api : IApi {
    override fun retrieveContent() = "Some Content"
}
```

I want to use the implementation in another class where the dependency injection is supposed to take place:

```
@Component
class SomeController {
    @Autowired lateinit var api: IApi
    fun printReceivedContent() {
        print(api.retrieveContent())
    }
}
```

However, the application terminates with the above-mentioned error message. My Spring config looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
open class DIConfig {
    @Bean
    open fun getApiInstance(): IApi = Api()
}
```

In the main function I load the application context and call the method:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val context = AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()
    context.register(DIConfig::class.java)
    context.refresh()

    val controller = SomeController()
    controller.printReceivedContent()
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring isn't involved if you just call the constructor yourself like that. Same as in Java,

```
val controller = context.getBean(SomeController::class.java)
```

Spring Framework 5.0 adds [Kotlin extensions](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/04/introducing-kotlin-support-in-spring-framework-5-0), so you could also write either one of

```
val controller = context.getBean<SomeController>()
val controller: SomeController = context.getBean()
```

Comment: Thanks! The way you described it works. In the configuration file, however, I need to add the following bean definition: `@Bean
open fun getSomeController() = SomeController()` Is there any way to omit this "unnecessary" code?

Answer (score 0):

your api is currently no a bean managed by spring, try annotating it with @Service or @Component

Answer (score -1):

The `@Autowired` is usually added to the setter of a property. So instead of using it for the property, you should explicitly annotate the setter:

```
@set:Autowired lateinit var api: IApi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.
Explicitly annotating the setter like
`lateinit var api: IApi
        @Autowired set`
doesn't work either.